# Tight subsubsequence implies tight

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence, polish-spaces

I am wondering whether the following result holds: Suppose $(P_n)$ is a sequence of probability measures on a complete separable metric space and every subsequence of $P_n$ has a further subsequence which is tight. Then $(P_n)$ is tight.

In the real setting (or even $\mathbb{R}^d$), the result is true: see [Prokhorov's Theorem-Prove if tight subsubsequence, then tight sequence.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773499/prokhorovs-theorem-prove-if-tight-subsubsequence-then-tight-sequence).

I have tried to mimic the proof given, but I am running into some difficulties. In fact, I am not sure the given solution is fully incorrect (the inequalities seem to be the wrong way round).

Anyways, I believe the proof should be quite similar with some modifications, by constructing a nested increasing sequence of compact sets (similar to the $[-j,j]$ in the real setting. Could anyone verify this? Thanks

Comment: "In fact, I am not sure the given solution is fully incorrect": I have edited.

Comment: Thanks @DavideGiraudo. However I can not follow why there are infinitely many $i$ for which $P_i(\mathbb{R}\setminus[-j,j])>\delta_0$. Doesn't the definition of not being tight imply the existence of an index $n_j$ for which the above holds? How did you deduce infinitely many $i$ from here? Thanks :)

Comment: I have added more details. In you case here it will work in the same way if the space is $\sigma$-compact. But for your setting I need to think more.

Comment: Okay thanks. I realised that I only required weak convergence of the subsubsequence instead of tightness - but this is just Prokhorov theorem. Still, the question is interesting and I am open to answers!